# When does an object get a objectID that is not temporary?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

I am inserting a new Folder entity into my model object context (MOC), that is a child of the master MOC. Before saving, [[newFolder objectID] isTemporaryId] returns YES. When I save first my MOC and then the master MOC and ask the [[newFolder objectID] isTemporaryId], it again says YES. I expected it to now be a persisted object, and indeed, if I interrogate the SQLite file, it contains the new folder. For the entire time of my running application, it will say YES. Not before I quit and restart, thus loading the object up from the store, does it say NO.

I always thought a NSManagedObject changed from a temporary object to a stored object with no longer a temporary objectID when it was saved. When does an object get a objectID that is not temporary?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: I should probably add that I cannot use "NSManagedObject *obj = [MOC existingObjectWithID:oid error:&error];" where oid is the (still temporary) ObjectID of the newly inserted & saved folder

Comment: So far, the only useful way out of this is to follow up a save-to-disk with [self.masterMOC reset];

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Objects in child contexts aren't altered by changes in the parent context until the objects are refreshed.  Perhaps refreshing the object after saving the parent context will do the trick.

If that doesn't work, there's always `-[NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:]`.

Comment: It's the child that is changed, not the parent. Then the child is saved first, then the parent. Thanks for the trick with obtainPermanentIDsForObjects. But I'd still very much like to know why the object ID doesn't refresh.

Comment: I understand—you change the object, save the child context, then save the parent context.  When you save the child context, it doesn't get a permanent ID; I'm theorizing that when you save the parent context, that only affects the parent context, so the child context doesn't see the permanent ID.  If true, refreshing the object should force the child context to get the new ID from the parent.

Comment: What way would you recommend for refreshing the object? When using the temporary ID for objectID, existingObjectWithID:error: returns an error, and objectWithID: gives the same object with the same temporary ID. Even after both child and parent are saved. resetting the parent MOC resolves this, but that's a very expensive resolution.

Comment: I'm suggesting you try `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`.

Comment: Precisely what I needed to know... thanks a lot it's been 2 lost hours until I found your answer. thank you thank you thank you +1 :)

Comment: Would you suggest use `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` in favour of `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` If so, why?

Comment: @LShi: I'd suggest trying refreshing first because I'm less certain that `-obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` will choose the same ID that the parent context did (instead of picking a new one), whereas if refreshing works, it will definitely pick the same ID.

Comment: Thanks. That really makes sense. In my current project I never `reset()` the main queue moc, which is a child moc of a background one. It seems even temporary `managedObjectIDs` work fine for me. I do keep these temporary IDs for refreshing UI when the user clicking here and there. But it seemed just **for one time** the moc didn't get me a related NSManagedObject. Maybe I was day dreaming but I thought I should be cautious now. I can't reproduce the problem though.